# Why does $(someElement).height() never calculate the height correctly for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, algorithm, responsive-design

I have a procedure

```
jQuery(function($){
    function makeParentHeightOfSmallestChild (parentSelector)
    {
        var parent = $(parentSelector);
        var children = parent.children();
        if (children.length < 2) return; 
        var smallestHeight = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        children.each(function(){
            var thisHeight = $(this).height();
            if (thisHeight < smallestHeight) smallestHeight = thisHeight;
        });
        parent.height(smallestHeight);
    }

    $(window).load(function(){
        makeParentHeightOfSmallestChild('#contact-page-container > .row');
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        makeParentHeightOfSmallestChild('#contact-page-container > .row');
    });

});
```

which is self-explanatory. The problem I'm having is that `smallestHeight` is coming out as a value that is clearly smaller than the actual smallest height of the elements that have been iterated over to calculate it. The elements are the two ones you can see in

```
   <div class="container" id="contact-page-container">       
        <h1>Get in touch</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <h3>Email</h3>
                <p>S,madsn sandaskldasjk laskldaskjd skajkasdkjas k</p>

                        <input type="text" value="Your Name"/>
                        <input type="text" value="Your Email Address" /> 
                        <textarea value="Your Message" rows="18">Your Message</textarea>                                   
            </div>
            <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <h3>Address</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <iframe class="same-height-as-width" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2686.2302199264063!2d-122.13376389999996!3d47.67994880000002!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54900d52444ba747%3A0x577e2db631b0711c!2s8620+154th+Ave+NE%2C+Redmond%2C+WA+98052!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1441747735537" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and when I look in Inspect Element the heights are 595.556 pixels and 747.778 pixels, but somehow the height of the parent is being set as 242 pixels. Why is that?

Comment: Try outerHeight() - which includes padding or outerHeight(true), which includes margin as well. http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

Comment: create demo with enough css to replicate problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider the difference between `.height()` and `.outerHeight()`

Here's a good [link](http://princepthomas.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/jquery-height-vs-outerheight.html) for you, good luck!

> #### jQuery height() vs outerHeight()
>
> **.height()**
>
> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements. This does not include the padding, border and margin.
>
> **.outerHeight([includeMargin])**
>
> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin.
>
> **"includeMargin"** is a optional boolean indicating whether to include the element's margin in the calculation.
>
> ```
> // returns height of browser viewport
> $(window).height(); 
>
> // returns height of HTML document
> $(document).height(); 
>
> // returns height of "IdofYourDIV" excluding padding, border and margin
> $("#IdofYourDIV").height();
>
> // returns height of "IdofYourDIV" including padding and border but excluding margin
> $("#IdofYourDIV").outerHeight(); 
>
> // returns height of "IdofYourDIV" including padding, border and margin
> $("#IdofYourDIV").outerHeight(true);
> ```

http://princepthomas.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/jquery-height-vs-outerheight.html

Comment: Can you please explain the specifics of what your answer is? Bring in the main points of why this answers the question, then provide the link for reference. The link may break/rot in the future and then your answer is no good any more...

Comment: I've edited your answer so it's formatting is fixed and directly answers the question - you should see it once peer reviewed. Note how to apply formatting in this way to your future questions and answers :)

Comment: @StevenAnderson I'm new here, so... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

After including to your code [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) values of height become integer. My example you can see on the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndriyK/g8os1x46/) where I also hidden all was outside `.row` what is `parentSelector`. Note I saw in end your code missed closing tag `</div>` maybe this a copy-paste mistake but be careful.
I hope this will help You.